# Magento 2.4.2 - on CMS page save "Unique constraint violation found" issue when using hierarchy

Tags: cms-pages, magento2.4.2

I am facing issue while saving CMS page when page hierarchy assigned to it. When I create a new page and save, it works fine but when I save it again it throws `Unique constraint violation found` error.

**Preconditions**

- Magento EE 2.4.2
- PHP 7.4.14
- MySQL 8.0.23

**Steps to reproduce**

- Create a Hierarchy by assigning existing CMS page to it (Ex. Helpful Links)
- Create a Page (Ex. Contact)
- Check off desired Hierarchy (Ex. Make Contact a child of Helpful Links)
- Save Page
- Edit Contact page and save again

It saves as expected when I won't select anything in Hierarchy section on CMS edit page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A patch is being available for this issue.

`MDVA-33606_EE_2.4.1_v1.composer.patch`

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-versions-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Hierarchy.php b/vendor/magento/module-versions-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Hierarchy.php
index 72996f7476d..6426aed16d5 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-versions-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Hierarchy.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-versions-cms/Block/Adminhtml/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Hierarchy.php
@@ -6,6 +6,7 @@
 namespace Magento\VersionsCms\Block\Adminhtml\Cms\Page\Edit\Tab;
 
 use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
+use Magento\VersionsCms\Model\Hierarchy\Node;
 
 /**
  * Cms Page Edit Hierarchy Tab Block
@@ -163,15 +164,15 @@ class Hierarchy extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template implements \Magento\Back
                 }
             } else {
                 foreach ($collection as $item) {
-                    if ($item->getLevel() == \Magento\VersionsCms\Model\Hierarchy\Node::NODE_LEVEL_FAKE) {
+                    if ($item->getLevel() == Node::NODE_LEVEL_FAKE) {
                         continue;
                     }
-                    /* @var $item \Magento\VersionsCms\Model\Hierarchy\Node */
+                    /* @var $item Node */
                     $node = [
                         'node_id' => $item->getId(),
                         'parent_node_id' => $item->getParentNodeId(),
                         'label' => $item->getLabel(),
-                        'store_label' => $this->getNodeStoreName((int)$item->getScopeId()),
+                        'store_label' => $this->getNodeStoreName((int)$item->getScopeId(), $item->getScope()),
                         'page_exists' => (bool)$item->getPageExists(),
                         'page_id' => $item->getPageId(),
                         'current_page' => (bool)$item->getCurrentPage(),
@@ -188,12 +189,18 @@ class Hierarchy extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template implements \Magento\Back
      * Return store name for node by scope_id
      *
      * @param int $scopeId
+     * @param string $scopeCode
      * @return string
      * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
      */
-    private function getNodeStoreName(int $scopeId)
+    private function getNodeStoreName(int $scopeId, string $scopeCode = Node::NODE_SCOPE_STORE)
     {
-        $scope = $this->storeManager->getStore($scopeId);
+        if ($scopeCode === Node::NODE_SCOPE_WEBSITE) {
+            $scope = $this->storeManager->getWebsite($scopeId);
+        } else {
+            $scope = $this->storeManager->getStore($scopeId);
+        }
+
         if (!$scope->getId()) {
             return 'All Store Views';
         }
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-versions-cms/Observer/Backend/CmsPageSaveAfterObserver.php b/vendor/magento/module-versions-cms/Observer/Backend/CmsPageSaveAfterObserver.php
index f60f078a763..9327551c2e5 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-versions-cms/Observer/Backend/CmsPageSaveAfterObserver.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-versions-cms/Observer/Backend/CmsPageSaveAfterObserver.php
@@ -11,6 +11,7 @@ use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
 use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
 use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeResolver;
+use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
 use Magento\VersionsCms\Helper\Hierarchy;
 use Magento\VersionsCms\Model\Hierarchy\Node as HierarchyNode;
 use Magento\VersionsCms\Model\ResourceModel\Hierarchy\Node;
@@ -131,7 +132,7 @@ class CmsPageSaveAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
                 continue;
             }
 
-            $requestUrl = $parentNode->getIdentifier() . '/' . $page->getIdentifier();
+            $requestUrl = $parentNode->getRequestUrl() . '/' . $page->getIdentifier();
             if ($this->isNodeExist($requestUrl, $nodeScopeId, (int)$parentNode->getId(), (int)$page->getId())) {
                 throw new LocalizedException(
                     __(
@@ -167,6 +168,9 @@ class CmsPageSaveAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
         }
 
         foreach ($pageStoreIds as $storeId) {
+            if ((int)$storeId === Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID) {
+                return true;
+            }
             $isScopeValid = $this->scopeResolver->isBelongsToScope(
                 $nodeScope,
                 $nodeScopeId,
@@ -193,10 +197,6 @@ class CmsPageSaveAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
     private function createNewNode(HierarchyNode $parentNode, array $pageData, int $sortOrder, string $pageIdentifier)
     {
         $newNode = clone $parentNode;
-        if ($parentNode->getScopeId() !== HierarchyNode::NODE_SCOPE_DEFAULT_ID) {
-            $newNode->setScope(HierarchyNode::NODE_SCOPE_STORE);
-        }
-        $newNode->setScopeId($parentNode->getScopeId());
 
         $newNode->addData(
             $pageData
```